# Powershell ForEach loop to add multiple domains to the zone map hkcu regkey

Tags: powershell

I have multiple sites that I want to add to HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\
I would rather do this with a Foreach loop so I don't have to run a single script individually.

if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\123.abc'))

{

New-Item -Path 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\123.abc'

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\123.abc' -Name https -Value 2 -Type DWord

}

I cannot seem to figure out the ForEach part

$domains = '123.abc', 'xyz.abc', 'abc.abc'

ForEach ($domains in $domains) {

.....

here is where I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$domains = '123.abc', 'xyz.abc', 'abc.abc'

foreach ($domain in $domains){

    $RegKey = 'HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
    Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\' + $domain

    if (-not(Test-Path $RegKey)){

        New-Item -Path $RegKey 
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name https -Value 2 -Type DWord
    }
}
```